# In iOS 11.2.*, messages sent with a $ symbol and/or "dollar/s" and a link in the message body render with the link being unclickable in iMessage

Tags: ios, iphone, ios11

In iOS 11.2.*, any message sent w/ a message body that contains a $ and/or the word "dollar/s" and a link in the message body render with the link not being clickable.

> e.g. Check out this link for $50 off: http://www.example.com
>   e.g. Checkout this link for 50 dollars off: http://www.example.com

In the above example, the message body will be fully delivered, but the link will NOT be clickable within iMessage. See screenshot below:

[image: unclickable link]

Curiously, if you use double dollar signs ($$), or a dollar sign followed by an alpha character (e.g. $a), or misspell dollars (e.g. dollarz) the issue is not present, i.e. the links are fully clickable. For example, these messages would properly display the links despite the inclusion of $ / dollar:

> Check out this link for $$50 off: http://www.example.com 
>   Check out this link for $a off: http://www.example.com 
>   Check out this link for 5 dollarz off: http://www.example.com

This issue does NOT appear to be fixed in future iOS release -- I just tested on 11.2.5 on Jan 4th 2018.

My hunch is that this bug is related to Apple's integration of Apple Pay into iMessage wherein they are likely parsing for currency keyword to suggest payment via Apple Pay. Does anyone know of any workarounds?

Comment: what about spaces? `$ 50`, or `US$50` or use the unicode zero width space: U+200B

Comment: @GradyPlayer US$50 does not work, $ 50 also does not work. the unicode suggestion is a good one, but would involve sending messages with UTF8 instead of GSM, which is considerably more expensive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug within a first party application at the user level, and should be reported to Apple as such.

Comment: Obligatory bug reporter link: [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)